# What does 'locals' stand for in thread dump?

Tags: java, jvm, threadpool, heap-memory

I have thread dump with next stacktrace info in it:

```
Thread 0x7d9e7140
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V (Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue;I)Z (ForkJoinPool.java:1824)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue;)V (ForkJoinPool.java:1693)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run()V (ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

  locals:
    objectId=0x965091b8, line=1
    objectId=0x7d9e8148, line=1
    objectId=0x7d9e7140, line=1
    objectId=0x965091b8, line=2
    objectId=0x7d9e8148, line=2
    objectId=0x7d9e7140, line=3
```

I was wondering what locals stand for? How do I map them do information in heap dump?

Answer (score 0):

"locals" are the variables used with a method.  http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/local-variables-in-java/